# I updated scikit.learn but I have still get this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.cross_validation'

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, linear-regression, data-analysis

I want to make linear regression and I have problem about scikit.learn. I updated from 20.1 to 20.2 but I have still get ModuleNotFoundError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cross-validation functionality has been moved to `model_selection`. To access it's functionality you may try:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate                                          
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict                          
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

See docs and examples at [Cross-validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate but I have taken this error TypeError: cross_validate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'test_size'

Comment: `cross_validate` does not have `test_size` param. What it has is `cv` which maybe an integer, specifying number of cv folds, or iterable, or generator, which return (train, test) indices. See [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html) for more and examples

Comment: import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/KURSAT/Desktop/Salary.csv')
print(data.head())
X=data.iloc[:,:-1].values
y=data.iloc[:,:-1].values
#Split on Datas
from sklearn.model_validation import test_train_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=test_train_split(X,y,test_size=1/3,random_state=0)
#RegressionLine
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor=LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train,y_train)
#Predict
y_predict=regressor.predict(X_test)
#DrawGraph